# Using Jquery: I want to place a div outside of div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to put a  tag as such a way like:

```
<div class="abc">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
<div>
```

using jquery i want to put  on top of 1st div that is present in this container.

Structure:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

</div>
```

Expected output:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="abc">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
<div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve this problem? We expect that you will make an attempt and do your research before posting and then, when you do post, that you'll post what you've tried along with a ***specific*** question about fixing the code. It's not appropriate to just post what you want and expect that we'll provide answers.

Comment: I tried multiple ways to solve this but i m not able to find the answer so thats why i have posted this.
can u please help me on this?

Comment: You should post the methods that you've tried along with a ***specific*** question about that attempt.

Comment: Well if you have truly "tried multiple ways to solve this", then pasting some of the code you have tried should be easy to do. Please edit your post and put your code there.

Answer (score 1):

It's seem like you need to use `.wrap` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Fistdiv" ).wrap( "<div class='abc'></div>" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">

    <div id="Fistdiv" class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="Trys/StartMap.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="Trys/StartMap.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="Trys/StartMap.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>

</div>
```

I added `id` to the first div to specify it.

Hope it's help.

Comment: this is kinda overlapping all the things.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery, just `this.parent`. If this doesn't work look through the scope chain.